# Spectral norm inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Suppose I have two matrices A, B

$$
A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}
$$
Then on what conditions on A and B will the followig ineqiality hold:
$$
||A+B||_2 \geq ||A||_2
$$

I for some reason feel that this would hold when the spaces spanned by the columns these matrices are different. But maybe I am wrong, or I cannot mathematically articulate it.

Comment: Using elementary properties, you can show that this inequality is equivalent to : $\left\langle 2A+B,B \right\rangle_{F} \geq 0$. It is probably possible to say more about this inequality, though.

Comment: @jibounet that's the Frobenius norm, not the spectral norm

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong.  In particular, if we take
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&100\\0&0}\\
B = \pmatrix{-1&-100\\1/100&1}
$$
Verify that the column space of the two matrices is different, but $\|A + B\| < \|A\|$.